# How to change time zone for Google cloud SQL?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Google SQL cloud platform
How to set

> -04:00

for time zone ?
It is for SQL server...

Comment: I believe this is always UTC for managed instances (Microsoft SQL Server) and cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding SQL Server is using time taken form operating system on which the instance is running. As Cloud SQL is 'serverless' solution you should not care about server underneath.

I noticed that Cloud MySQL has such flag, but both PostgreSQL and SQL server does not. This is because the flags are provided by database supplier. If you follow the  links on the flags in [Cloud SQL documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags#list-flags-mysql) your are forwarded to database vendor documentation. I think time zone is missing in Cloud SQL Server as this feature is not available in at least in version 2017.

As a consequence timezone is always set to UTC.

I hope it will help!